# Compare two vectors and match only once if integer only appears once in vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors that I want to compare. I have tried with match() and %in% but it does not give me the result I want. The solution should be in **R base**.

*Input*

```
   a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
   b = c(1,1,2)
```

*Tested Solutions*

```
b %in% a
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

However, I want it to say TRUE **FALSE** TRUE, because "1" appears only once in a.

Is there any way of doing this in R Base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Append " 1" to the first occurrence of each entry, " 2" to the second and so on.  Then use those.

```
f <- function(x) paste(x, seq_along(x))
ave(b, b, FUN = f) %in% ave(a, a, FUN = f)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

**2)** There are no dupliates in a in the example and if this is the case then another approach is check whether each element of b is in a but reject it if is it a duplicate.

```
(b %in% a) & !duplicated(b)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

### Note

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  b <- c(1, 1, 2)  # inputs
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if a could have duplicates since there were no duplicates in a in the example but if there can be then, yes, (2) would not be applicable.  Have clarified that.